# I don't understand this theorem about covering spaces or it is a typo?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, orientation

Isn't it a trivial conclusion the first part of the following theorem from Theodore Frankel book ([The Geometry of Physics: An Introduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=2iq2EGNgX24C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA575#v=onepage&q&f=false)) or it is a simple typo?

> [**Theorem**](https://books.google.com/books?id=2iq2EGNgX24C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA575#v=onepage&q&f=false): The orientable cover of $M$ is always orientable. The number
>   of sheets is $1$ if $M$ is orientable and $2$ if $M$ is not orientable.

Comment: To me it looks like it should be universal cover rather than orientable cover

Comment: You might be fooled by the choice of terminology "orientable cover". Think of this as an [a posterior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori) terminology. Still, though, with improved terminology, this issue goes away. For example, some authors use the terminology "orientation cover" instead of "orientable cover".

Comment: By the way if I'm not mistaken the number of sheets doesn't depend on orientability : it's always $2$. The number of connected components, however, varies

Comment: @Max: It seems that's how it is written in that textbook. My guess is that this physics textbook is using "sheets" in a way that sounds nonstandard to our mathematical ears, i.e. as a synonym for "connected components".

Comment: @LeeMosher Ah so something along the lines of "number of sheets in one of the connected components" ? That's reasonable enough, but sounds unpractical

Comment: Something like that. I agree that its a misuse of terminology *at best*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this paragraph on the page 573 in the same book:

> ... If $M$ is orientable, then
>   the covering obtained reduces to $M$ itself, but if $M$ is not orientable we obtain a new
>   space $\overline{M}$. In any case $\overline{M}$ is called the **orientable cover** of $M$, for, as we shall see, this
>   $\overline{M}$ is always orientable.

So the theorem is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this theorem is trivial depends on the definition of orientable cover. With that name one would hope that it is orientable but if that is not part of the definition than it has to be proven.